# Icon resources?

Tags: icons

Not a technical question lads but ive been looking for a set of icons for a room reservation  thing that im working on.
theres loads of icon resources around the web alrite but is there a decent place to go for some quality free icons that anyone can recommend??

Comment: Next time tag a not-programming-related question with "not-programming-related"

Comment: I disagree.  Adding icons to one's product is part of the job, and specific to the job of programming.

Comment: The question this was marked a duplicate of has been removed.  I believe this is a relevant question for developers, we're often asked to implement icons, but no artist is provided to the team, so we want icons that have already been developed by someone else to import.

Answer (score 5):

I usually go the [IconArchive](http://www.iconarchive.com/) or [famfamfam](http://www.famfamfam.com/) when I'm looking for some tiny ones. Both of the sites have loads of free to use icons sets.

Answer (score 4):

I usually use either well-known an re-usable icon sets, or bespoke search engines to find specific icons (and preferably the whole set they belong to and their license)

## Icon Sets

- famfamfam
- fugue
- glaze
- tango
- openiconlibrary
- ...

## Search Engines

- http://images.google.com *(always handy, w/ settings for "Icons" and "Commercial Reuse" if needed)*
- http://www.iconfinder.com/ *(quite good, with direct links to the sets and authors' homepages)*
- http://www.iconarchive.com/ *(also quite good)*
- http://www.findicons.com/ *(not as good, but worth a shot)*

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach would be to Google and do a image search for some related term e.g. "no dogs" or "cable tv". You get the idea.

Then simply grab all the icons relevant to your topic.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com) as a resource for icons. They have articles linking to high quality resources for icons such as this [icon set](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/05/21/40-professional-icon-sets-for-free-download/).

Answer (score 0):

Do a search for Creative Commons Icon Sets, these are free to use with attribution.

Answer (score 0):

[Seanau icon](http://www.seanau.com)s is great!

Want to free icons, I'm recommend [Iconsfind.com](http://www.iconsfind.com)